# Android Bitmap parcel Unmarshalling error while broadcast it

Tags: java, android

I have a Parcelable Contact Objects. I need to place them in ArrayList and broadcast it to the Activity. Getting error while reading the ArrayList in broadcast listener. I tried alot to resolve this issue. But could not find any solution to fix it.

### Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=ip. flg=0x10 (has extras) } in io.HomeActivity$1@20d66f72
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:876)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@13cda10b: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7274601 at offset 352
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2228)
            at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
            at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:799)
            at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:5126)
            at io.HomeActivity$1.onReceive(HomeActivity.java:149)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

### Contact

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable{

    private String id;
    private String lookupKey;
    private String dispName;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNo;
    private Bitmap photoThumbnail;
    private String statusMsg;
    private int isRapo;


    public Contact(){}

    public Contact(String id, String lookupKey, String dispName, String email, String mobileNo, Bitmap photoThumbnail,String statusMsg,int isRapo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lookupKey = lookupKey;
        this.dispName = dispName;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
        //this.photoThumbnail = photoThumbnail;
        this.statusMsg = statusMsg;
        this.isRapo = isRapo;
    }

    protected Contact(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        lookupKey = in.readString();
        dispName = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        mobileNo = in.readString();
        //photoThumbnail = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
        //photoThumbnail =  (Bitmap)in.readValue(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
        photoThumbnail = (Bitmap)in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
        statusMsg = in.readString();
        isRapo = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Contact> CREATOR = new Creator<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Contact(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Contact[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Contact[size];
        }
    };

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLookupKey() {
        return lookupKey;
    }

    public void setLookupKey(String lookupKey) {
        this.lookupKey = lookupKey;
    }

    public String getDispName() {
        return dispName;
    }

    public void setDispName(String dispName) {
        this.dispName = dispName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public Bitmap getPhotoThumbnail() {
        return photoThumbnail;
    }

    public void setPhotoThumbnail(Bitmap photoThumbnail) {
        this.photoThumbnail = photoThumbnail;
    }

    public String getStatusMsg() {
        return statusMsg;
    }

    public void setStatusMsg(String statusMsg) {
        this.statusMsg = statusMsg;
    }

    public int getIsRapo() {
        return isRapo;
    }

    public void setIsRapo(int isRapo) {
        this.isRapo = isRapo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dispName;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(lookupKey);
        dest.writeString(dispName);
        dest.writeString(email);
        dest.writeString(mobileNo);
        //dest.writeParcelable();
        /*if(photoThumbnail != null) {
            photoThumbnail.writeToParcel(dest, 5);
        }*/
        if(photoThumbnail != null){
            dest.writeParcelable(photoThumbnail,flags);
        }
        dest.writeString(statusMsg);
        dest.writeInt(isRapo);
    }
}
```

### Service

```
contactResIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("clist", contactList);
```

### Broadcast Listener

```
private BroadcastReceiver contactsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GOT Contacts response from service!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("@HomeActivity", "GOT Service response.");
            /*Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            ArrayList<Parcelable> clist =  data.getParcelableArrayList("clist");*/
            ArrayList<Contact> clist =  intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("clist");
            if(clist != null){
                String s = clist.get(0).getClass().toString();
                Log.d("@HomeActivity","CONTACTS LIST :"+s+"##"+String.valueOf(clist.size()));
            }
```

Comment: Is there some case in that your photoThumbnail is `null`?

Comment: If i set dummy bitmap for null photoThumbnail objects then it is coming fine with out any error. Can you tell me null Bitmap objects can't be parcelable?. If it is not possible, can you tell me how can i avoid by setting dummy bitmap in null case? and if is set a big bitmap it is giving Failed Binder transaction error

Comment: I answered this question, if it solves your problem you can accept it so others can check it as the right answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should avoid putting a bitmap into a Parcel. It usually uses a large amount of memory and I've experienced some [TransactionTooLargeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) when transferring large parcelables (a limitation of 1Mb). Instead you could write just a `String` or an identifier that represents that thumbnail and load it again if needed.

That being said, you can try the following (check for null).

Change the constructor:

```
protected Contact(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    lookupKey = in.readString();
    dispName = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    mobileNo = in.readString();
    if (in.readByte() == 1) {
        photoThumbnail = (Bitmap) in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
    }
    statusMsg = in.readString();
    isRapo = in.readInt();
}
```

Change the writeToParcel

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(lookupKey);
    dest.writeString(dispName);
    dest.writeString(email);
    dest.writeString(mobileNo);
    if (photoThumbnail != null){
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeParcelable(photoThumbnail,flags);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    }
    dest.writeString(statusMsg);
    dest.writeInt(isRapo);
}
```